# Flash/XML breaklines & hidden characters

Tags: xml, flash, eclipse, cdata

I got this problem, when edit my xml everything on a next line renders two breaklines

```
<![CDATA[Line one
Line two
Line three
]]>
```

Renders in flash as

```
Line One

Line Two

Line Three
```

Now I researched this before and it had something to do with hidden breakline characters, Im using Flexbuilder and or Aptana to edit the xml, but how do I avoid having two breaklines when I want one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash interprets both `\r` and `\n` as new line characters. If your input contains windows line endings (`\r\n`), then you see a blank line in the output.

To solve your problem, use the following regex to replace two consecutive occurrences of `\r` and `\n` with one before you output your data.

```
var newline:RegExp = /\r\n|\n\r/g;
var input:String = "your XML CDATA input";
var output:String = input.replace(newline, "\n");
```

Actually it is unlikely that `\n\r` ever occurs, but since we are already replacing, we can fix these invalid line endings as well.

Comment: makes sense, but isnt this a bit of an overkill work around ?

Comment: It's the workaround that prevents the problem from ever surfacing again, independently of your editing habits/platforms and data sources. Wrap it in a function and you are done. Tweaking your editor works only as long as you don't forget to do it, tweaking external datasources may not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're inserting the wrong end-of-line characters.  Usually your choices are: cr-lf, cr, and lf.  The first works well on windows, the second on Mac, the third on most flavors of Unix.  Try setting your editor to use lf (\n).